# UITableViewCell get deleted directly by tapping delete control on the left but not show delete button on the right

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, edit

When I involve `[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES]`, delete control shows on every cell on the left,what I want to do is to get the event when I tap delete control,and directly delete cell but not to show delete button on the right.

I know apple's standard way to do this is to show delete button on the right, and when I tap it ,datasource's

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

gets involved, the reason I don't want to do like this is my cell is customised by scrollview which scroll horizontally so scroll to show delete button would made it a mess, so I wouldn't implement

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in my datasource.

Have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way u do is, customising the cell and put your own way of deleting the cell for example,

create a new custom cell by subclassing the `UITableviewCell` name it as something like `CustomCellTableViewCell`
in `CustomCellTableViewCell.h` define a delegate method for example,

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @class CustomCellTableViewCell;
 @protocol CellDelegate <NSObject>
 - (void)deleteCell:(CustomCellTableViewCell *)cell;
 @end


 @interface CustomCellTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
 + (CustomCellTableViewCell *)createCell;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *deleteButton;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionLabel;
 @property (weak,nonatomic)  id<CellDelegate> cellDelegate;
 - (IBAction)deleteAction:(id)sender;
 - (void)showDeleteButton;
 - (void)hideDeleteButton;
 @end
```

and in `CustomCellTableViewCell.xib` add a button and set label connect to  `deleteButton` and `descriptionLabel`

in `CustomCellTableViewCell.m` file

```
 #import "CustomCellTableViewCell.h"

 @implementation CustomCellTableViewCell

 - (void)awakeFromNib {
  // Initialization code
   }


 - (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
  {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if(self)
    {
      self = [CustomCellTableViewCell createCell];
    }
    return self;
 }

 + (CustomCellTableViewCell *)createCell
 {
     NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
     if ([arrayOfViews count] < 1) {
        return nil;
     }
     for (id item in arrayOfViews) {
       if([item isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
           return item;
     }
     return nil;
 }

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
  [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

   // Configure the view for the selected state
 }

 - (IBAction)deleteAction:(id)sender {
    if([self.cellDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(deleteCell:)])
    {

       [self.cellDelegate deleteCell:self];
    }
  }

 - (void)showDeleteButton
 {
   CGRect destRect = self.descriptionLabel.frame;
   destRect.origin.x += 80;
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.descriptionLabel.frame = destRect;
   }];
 }

 - (void)hideDeleteButton
 {
   CGRect destRect = self.descriptionLabel.frame;
   destRect.origin.x = 0;
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
     self.descriptionLabel.frame = destRect;
   }] ;

 }
 @end
```

and in controller `.m` file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   stringsArray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"apple",@"dell",@"windows",@"nokia",@"sony",@"hp",@"lenovo", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;  
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [stringsArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SuggestionCell"];
  if(cell == nil)
  {
     cell = [[CustomCellTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SuggestionCell"];
  }

  if(customEditTableView)
     [cell showDeleteButton];
  else
     [cell hideDeleteButton];

  cell.cellDelegate = self;
  cell.descriptionLabel.text = [stringsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return 50.0f;
}
- (IBAction)deleteCellsAction:(id)sender
{
  if(customEditTableView)
      customEditTableView = NO;
  else
      customEditTableView = YES;

  [self.aTableView reloadData];

}

- (void)deleteCell:(CustomCellTableViewCell *)cell
{
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.aTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
   [stringsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self.aTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

try out in new project u will get it

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this thing using `UIViewController`

Add `tableview` and `tableviewcell` in `UIViewController`

I have achive this same thing using `swift`. It will give you idea how to do in `Objective-C`

Below is Code:

```
var data:[String] = ["One","Three","Four","Five","Six"]
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel.text = self.data[indexPath.row]

    if editing
    {
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Button-Delete-icon.png")
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "")
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editing
    {
        self.data.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    }
}

override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Hope It will Help